# Do I need to create Partition in Linux 3.4

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage, fdisk, disk-management

My question is regarding partition(creating manually).

1. Do i need to create a partition in Linux 3.4 to save files & documents.In windows if the partition is not created system will still run however any damage to the system will result in file loss. is this equally applicable to Linux 3.4
2. If I have to create a partition, I understand that I have to create provision for /boot,/(root),swap and /home.

Can I create 2 /home similar to Local Disk E: and Local Disk D: in windows for my files,documents,Pictures.etc.. ?

Comment: What is Linux 3.4?

Comment: Linux 3.4 is the newest version of Linux Lite

Comment: Linux Lite is not offical varient of Ubuntu.

Comment: I never said Ubuntu I said Linux Lite. Anyways Linux Lite's recent version is 3.6 https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/release-announcements/linux-lite-3-6-final-released/

Comment: Yes, but AskUbuntu is for people to ask questions about Ubuntu and its offical varients. You should post it in Unix & Linux Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: Mate, I am new here(you can see that from my rating)I am not aware of so called rules(asking my questions only to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange forum) otherwise i would not be asking questions like partitioning. I am a user using an old PC and as ubuntu was not working i have to look for a lite version of ubuntu i got first Lubuntu but the graphic was not even decent and i got this(Linux Lite 3.4) from internet, working perfect . I always appreciate the knowledge bank of ubuntu forum and hence it was my natural choice to check here. Not anymore.very unfortunate & unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

1. No.
2. No. That is not true. Only / is mandatory (that is your C: in Windows). swap can be a file too and does not need to be a partition/mountpoint.

Creating partitions in Linux is just making the system more user friendly.

I put all my personal stuff on a partition /discworld/ so I can format my system besides that partition, I mound /discworld/ and have a fresh installation. I don't even use /home/ anymore.

It is totally possible to not create more than the base / and use Ubuntu without a problem. If you put your personal files somewhere in /home/$USER/Downloads/ or  /home/$USER/Documents/ or  /home/$USER/Desktop/ all you need to do is make a backup of those and you can put it back after a re-install. And when you do have trouble booting you can always backup those files from a live session.

> Can I create 2 /home similar to Local Disk E: and Local Disk D: in windows for my files,documents,Pictures.etc.. ?

No that is not how Ubuntu/Linux works. In Linux you create partitions and give them a mount point; that is a unique DIRECTORY name that is placed in / (C:). When you look at / from commandline or Nautilus you will see those directories and can navigate into them.

"2 /home/" would be 2 users.

Comment: Hello Rinzwind, thank you for your comment. You have mentioned "I put all my personal stuff on a partition /discworld/ so I can format my system besides that partition, I mound /discworld/ and have a fresh installation. I don't even use /home/ anymore." can you please help me how you did that.

Comment: At the partition part of the install create a 25Gb partition for / and put the remainder in a partition you give a name yourself and install it (that would be D: but we get to choose our own label ;) ).  You can then "chown" the partition to your user and put anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

1) My Answer is yes, it is prescribed to create partition for home in any linux distributions. Because, if you mis-configure something, you will lose your valuable data. Even if you want to change your distributions you will face the same issue.

2) You can have only 1 home partition per user. But if you want, you can mount unallocated hard-disk space as suppurate sda.

Being debian based destro. I hope this will work in ubuntu too.

https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1609